# GKE w/ Terraform - set autoscaling_profile

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have scale down issue on my GKE cluster and found out with the right configuration I can solve this.

As the terraform [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#autoscaling_profile) I can use the arguement `autoscaling_profile` and set it to `OPTIMIZE_UTILIZATION`

Like so :

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "k8s_cluster" {
  
[...]
  
  cluster_autoscaling {
    enabled = true
    autoscaling_profile = "OPTIMIZE_UTILIZATION"
    resource_limits {
      resource_type = "cpu"
      minimum = 1
      maximum = 4
    }
    resource_limits {
      resource_type = "memory"
      minimum = 4
      maximum = 16
    }
  }
}
```

But I got this error :

> Error: Unsupported argument on modules/gke/main.tf line 70, in resource "google_container_cluster" "k8s_cluster":
> 70:     autoscaling_profile = "OPTIMIZE_UTILIZATION"
>
> An argument named "autoscaling_profile" is not expected here.

I don't get it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Add below parameter to the definition of your resource (at the top):

- `provider = google-beta`

---

More explanation:

`autoscaling_profile` as shown in the documentation is a **beta** feature. This means that it will need to use different provider: `google-beta`.

You can read more about it by following official documentation:

- *[Terraform.io: Using the google beta provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/guides/provider_versions.html#using-the-google-beta-provider)*

Focusing on most important parts from above docs:

How to use it:

> To use the google-beta provider, simply set the provider field on each resource where you want to use google-beta.
>
> ```
> resource "google_compute_instance" "beta-instance" {
>  provider = google-beta
>  # ...
> }
> ```

Disclaimer about usage of `google` and `google-beta`:

> If the provider field is omitted, Terraform will implicitly use the google provider by default **even if you have only defined a google-beta provider block**.

---

Adding to the whole explanation your `GKE` cluster definition should look like this:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "k8s_cluster" {
  
[...]

  provider = google-beta # <- HERE IT IS
  
  cluster_autoscaling {
    enabled = true
    autoscaling_profile = "OPTIMIZE_UTILIZATION"
    resource_limits {
      resource_type = "cpu"
      minimum = 1
      maximum = 4
    }
    resource_limits {
      resource_type = "memory"
      minimum = 4
      maximum = 16
    }
  }
}
```

You will also need to run:

- `$ terraform init`